# Enquiry on Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a cartesian product $A=A_1×A_2×A_3....A_m $. Now consider if $A $ is non empty then each $A_i$ is non empty. But is the converse true. I am thinking it is true.  But I don't know for sure. Any help would be appriciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If each $A_i$ is non-empty, we can pick an element $a_i \in A_i$ from each. Then $(a_1,\ldots,a_m) \in A$ is an element of the Cartesian product, so the latter is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

There are different set-theoretic ways to define $\prod_{i=1}^nA_i.$  In a particular context, one way may be more convenient than  another. We may define the product as the set of functions from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $\cup_{i=1}^nA_i$ that satisfy $f(i)\in A_i$ for each $i\in \{1,...,n\}.$

For the Q, the case $n=1$ and $A_1\ne \phi$ is fairly trivial.

Suppose $A_i\ne \phi$ for $1\leq i\leq n+1$ and that $\prod_{i=1}^nA_i\ne \phi.$ Then there exists $f\in \prod_{i=1}^nA_i$ and  $x\in A_{n+1},$ whereupon $f\cup \{(n+1,x)\}\in \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i.$

So we have the result by induction on $n.$

This will not work for $\prod_{i\in J}A_i$ when $J$ is not finite, without the Axiom of Choice (AC). In fact, one of many equivalent versions of AC is that for all $J$ and all $\{A_i:i\in J\}$, if  $J\ne \phi$ and $A_i\ne \phi$ for each $i\in J$, then $\prod_{i\in J}A_i\ne \phi.$